# Android how to achieve 3d like action bar in play books app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am looking to implement a 3d like `ActionBar` shown here. Here there is **thin dark blue line** below the actual `ActionBar`. How do i implement that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using a couple of different methods.

**Use a View**

You could add a `View` that rests at the top of your layout, or just below the `ActionBar` then set its background accordingly.

**Apply it directly to the ActionBar**

1. Apply it via code: To apply the image via code, see [ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
2. Apply it via style: If you'd like to apply it via a style, refer to the official Android guide on [Styling the ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

**Creating the Drawable**

As far as the effect you're looking for goes, I think you want something like this: [image: action-bar-bg]

That was created using Photoshop and the [9-Patch generator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) in the SDK tools. You could also use the [Simple Nine Patch Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) to create one.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation here

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Just apply the style you wish to use to the relevant part of the action bar.